# laravel doesnt show image from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

ı tried this way in the productTableSeeder

`'image' =>asset('img/product.jpg')`  but it doesnt appear

and ı replace in env file   `APP_URL=http://localhost`   to `APP_URL=http://localhost:8080`

so please help me

Comment: is this image in your public folder?

Comment: @Joseph yes it is in public folder

Answer (score 0):

The `public` disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly accessible. By default, the `public` disk uses the `local` driver and stores these files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`

To create the symbolic link, you may use the `storage:link` Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Once a file has been stored and the symbolic link has been created, you can create a URL to the files using the asset helper:

```
echo asset('storage/file.txt');
```

To generate the URL you may use the `url` method to get the URL for the given file. If you are using the `local` driver, this will typically just prepend `/storage` to the given path and return a relative URL to the file. If you are using the s3 driver, the fully qualified remote URL will be returned:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$url = Storage::url('file.jpg');
```